# Exception occurred when submitting a package to Packagist. How to solve?

Tags: exception, doctrine, packagist

I'm tying to submit a package (staring with the project) to Packagist, but I'm having the following error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException] An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES (?)' with params {"1":"Mathematica"}: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Mathematica' for key 'name_idx'
```

The url of my project is:
 https://github.com/GarouDan/phpmath.git

Packagist url: https://packagist.org/packages/garoudan/phpmath

`composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "garoudan/phpmath",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Library to run Mathemtica functions trought PHP.",
    "keywords": ["php","PHP","mathematica","Mathematica","MathKernel","mathkernel","math","MathematicaScript","mathematicascript"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/GarouDan/phpmath",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Danilo Araújo Silva",
            "email": "silva.danilo.araujo@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://daniloaraujosilva.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Backend" : "core"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a SQL unique constraint violation. It's probably because you have lowercase and capitalized versions of all your tags, and they're using a case insensitive DB. Try submitting it with just one of each tag.

Comment: This works (I'd find this same solution yesterday, but the strange thing is looks like `PHP` and `php` works, but `Mathematica` and `mathematica` not). Thx.

Comment: My guess is that the PHP tag already exists, so it does a "find" to get that tag entity. But Mathematica isn't there yet, so it's trying to insert both. But since they're using case insensitive DB, you don't need it both ways anyway.

Comment: The bug is now fixed in Packagist by the way.